# Prove asymptotically equal using Stirling's formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

How would you prove $ \binom{2n}{n} $ ~ $ \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{πn}} $

Using Stirling's formula: $ n! $ ~ $ (\frac{n}{e})^n\sqrt{2πn} $

Comment: $\binom{2n}{n}$ is `\binom{2n}{n}`. :)

Comment: Do you have any ideans regarding this problem?

Comment: Do you know how to express $\binom{2n}{n}$ as a product of factorials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$C_{n}^{2n}=\frac{2n!}{n!n!}\sim\frac{(\frac{2n}{e})^{2n}\sqrt{4\pi{n}}}{(\frac{n}{e})^{2n}2\pi{n}}=\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi{n}}}$$

Comment: Sorry can you explain how you got this? Like what theorems you used?

Comment: I used the Stirling's formula)

Comment: For the last step, is it just plain simplifying? I'm having trouble understanding how you got from the 3rd to lest simplification

Comment: Yes)) simply cut the fraction)